# Work done by force F from (0,0,0) to (1,1,1) along curve $x=t$, $y=t^2$, $z=t^4$

Tags: calculus, integration

Find the work done by $F(x,y,z) =e^{y+2z}(i+xj+2xk)$ from $(0,0,0)$ to $(1,1,1)$ along curve $x=t$ , $y=t^2$ , $z=t^4$

My attempt:

Let $c(t) = (t,t^2,t^4)$ from $t=0 $ to $ t=1$.

Then $c'(t)= (1,2t,4t^3)$.

Work done is

$$\int_0^1 F(c(t)) . c'(t) dt = \int_0^1 e^{t^2+2t^4}(i+tj+2tk) . (1,2t,4t^3) dt\ $$

But don't know how to integrate $e^{t^2+2t^4}$

Did I do something wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: is the field conservative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint

Try to differentiate $te^{t^2+2t^4}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You have a dot product of two vectors which you haven't calculated yet: $$(\textbf{i}+t\textbf{j}+2t\textbf{k})\cdot(1, 2t, 4t^3)=1\cdot 1+t\cdot 2t+2t\cdot 4t^3 \text{ etc.}$$
Can you take it from there?

Comment: How do you plan to proceed? I mean integration part?

Comment: You need $\vec F • \vec ds$, have you checked if your parameter is the s ?(Length of curve)